# CORS и html2canvas

Tags: google-chrome, openlayers, cors, html2canvas

Здравствуйте! Для конвертации части страницы в картинку использую `html2canvas`.

```
html2canvas(mapElem, {
                useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                mapImg = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    ...
```

Выставляю `useCORS: true`, т.к. часть контента - это картинки, получаемые с геосервера.
В firefox всё отлично работает, а вот в chrome выдаёт ошибку

> Image from origin 'http://geo1.joxnet:8080' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так? И как исправить?

UPD: если в chrome поставить галку "disable cache" то проблема исчезает.

UPD2: конвертирую я карту на OpenLayers2 для печати, там можно получать с геосервера изображения и кешировать их, а можно не кешировать. Отключения кеширования при печати решает мою проблему.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350540/rgbaster-image-from-origin-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resou http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71630/font-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy-no-access-co Это не то же самое?

Comment: Возможно, но вопрос в том числе в том, почему тогда всё в firefox dвсё работает нормально?

Comment: По состоянию на середину 2012: Chrome does not support localhost for CORS requests (an open bug since 2010). Как сейчас, не знаю. Может до сих пор так и есть.

Comment: Пробовал и по IP заходить, та же ситуация.

Comment: UPD: если в chrome поставить галку "disable cache" то проблема исчезает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения карты при печати использую `urls.geoServerTestUrl` вместо `urls.geoServerCacheTestUrl`, это решает мою проблему.